# Layer in Leaflet JS doesnt show again when check the control layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use the leaflet control layer to show up and remove the layer when I didn't wanna show the layer. when I uncheck my control layer it worked properly. the layer can disappear, but when I check again the control layer, the layer didn't show again. but there is no error in the console .[image]

```
var pieChartGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
        
        vals.forEach(val => {

        var pictures = L.marker(val.location, {
            icon: L.divIcon({
                className: 'leaflet-echart-icon',
                iconSize: [160, 160],
                html: '<div id="marker' + val.id + '" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; position: relative; background-color: transparent;"></div>'
            })
        }).addTo(pieChartGroup);
        //  Based on the prepared dom, initialize the echarts instance
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('marker' + val.id));
        //  Specify chart configuration items and data
        option = {
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'item',
                formatter: "{a} <br/>{b}: {c} ({d}%)"
            },
            series: [{
                name: val.nama,
                type: 'pie',
                radius: ['10', '25'],
                avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false,
                        position: 'center'
                    },
                    emphasis: {
                        show: true,
                        textStyle: {
                            fontSize: '18',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                },
                labelLine: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                data: [{
                    value: val.MB,
                    name: 'Masih Bersekolah'
                }, {
                    value: val.TBL,
                    name: 'Tidak Bersekolah Lagi'
                }, {
                    value: val.TBPS,
                    name: 'Tidak/Belum Pernah Bersekolah'
                }]
            }]
        };
        //  Use the configuration items and data you just specified to display the chart.
        myChart.setOption(option);
        }
        )

        var baseLayers = {
        "OpenStreetMap": LayerKita,
        "OpenCycleMap": L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
        "Outdoors": L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
        };

        var overlays = {
        "Bersekolah" : pieChartGroup
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I think you need to re-run `var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('marker' + val.id)); ... setOptions() ` But don't ask me how